# jsPdf and html2Canvas not able to show s3 bucket images

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, html2canvas

I'm working on a feature where I need to download a React component containing images as a PDF using jsPdf and html2canvas. However, when attempting to use S3 images from my AWS bucket, the downloaded PDF doesn't display any images, and I encounter the following CORS error:

```
Access to image at 'https://test-bucket-mezink.s3.amazonaws.com/Group+169033.png' from origin 'http://dev.mezink.com:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've configured my S3 CORS policy to allow public access to such images. Here's my CORS configuration:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
        "AllowedMethods": ["GET"],
        "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Despite this configuration, the images can be fetched and displayed on my website, but they don't show up in the downloaded PDF. I've tried various solutions, including using html-to-image and html2image, but the CORS error persists.

I'm running out of options and would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!